# WooCommerce – template_redirect if is_checkout AND order has been paid?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, template-redirect

In my WooCommerce store I would like to redirect to a custom 'thank you page' after payment has been completed. I'm using this code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // I assume this is where I go wrong. Probably this is empty?

    if ( is_checkout() && 0 == WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) {
       wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); // redirect to home if empty cart on checkout page
       exit;
    } else if ( is_checkout() && **somehow check if $order has been paid?** ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'www.myurl.com' ); // if order has been paid for go here. this never triggers.
        exit;
    }
}
```

I assume that my problem is that the $order_id is empty, but my debugging skills suck so I don't know how to actually verify that to even get started.

I know of the $order->get_status(). I suppose this is called a method? If I try that in the place of ** ** I get a php fatal error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you want more informations about the fatal error, you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: in woocommerce, the cart is empty when the order is created then you cannot do that at this place. i recommend to use the filter `woocommerce_payment_successful_result` to customise the redirection URL : https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#925

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at this filter soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. woocommerce_payment_succesful_result guided me in the right direction, although it wasn't the final answer. function is_wc_endpoint_url() is really useful here, it checks where woocommerce is about to redirect next.

```
// redirect empty checkouts and completed orders.
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'myfunction' );
function myfunction() {

    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) && isset( $_GET['key'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect('www.myurl.com'); // go to custom page if order has been received
        exit;
    }

    if ( is_checkout() && 0 == WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) {
       wp_safe_redirect( home_url() ); // if trying to access checkout with empty cart go back
       exit;
    }  
}
```